# How can I change the colours of SCM diff decorations in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

VS Code has diff decorations in its Explorer View, tab handles, Source Control View, editor gutter, editor minimap, and editor scrollbars ("overview rulers"). How can I change the colours of the source control diff decorations in each of those places?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following colour customization points (this goes in [settings.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson)):

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    // for the editor gutter:
    "editorGutter.addedBackground": "#00cf00",
    "editorGutter.modifiedBackground": "#0080ff",
    "editorGutter.deletedBackground": "#cf0000",
    // for the minimap:
    "minimapGutter.addedBackground": "#00cf00",
    "minimapGutter.modifiedBackground": "#0080ff",
    "minimapGutter.deletedBackground": "#cf0000",
    // for the editor scrollbar
    "editorOverviewRuler.addedForeground": "#00cf00",
    "editorOverviewRuler.modifiedForeground": "#0080ff",
    "editorOverviewRuler.deletedForeground": "#cf0000",
    // for the Explorer View, Source Control View, and tab handles
    "gitDecoration.addedResourceForeground": "#00cf00",
    "gitDecoration.modifiedResourceForeground": "#0080ff",
    "gitDecoration.deletedResourceForeground": "#cf0000",
    "gitDecoration.stageAddedResourceForeground": "#00cf00",
    "gitDecoration.stageModifiedResourceForeground": "#0080ff",
    "gitDecoration.stageDeletedResourceForeground": "#cf0000",
    // bonus:
    "gitDecoration.conflictingResourceForeground": "#ff0000",
    "gitDecoration.ignoredResourceForeground": "#ff0000",
    "gitDecoration.renamedResourceForeground": "#ff0000",
    "gitDecoration.submoduleResourceForeground": "#ff0000",
    "gitDecoration.untrackedResourceForeground": "#ff0000",
}
```

The values above are just placeholders. Adjust them to your liking.